# Relative volume of $\delta$-fattening (neighborhood) of a compact set

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, volume, geometric-measure-theory

For a non-empty, compact set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, the [$\delta$-fattening](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Hausdorff_distance#/Definition) of $A$, $A_\delta$, is defined to be the set
$$
A_\delta = \cup_{a \in A} B_{\delta}(a),
$$
where $B_\delta(a)$ denotes the closed ball centered at $A$ with radius $\delta$.

Is it possible to establish an upper bound on $\mu(A_\delta)$ in terms of $\mu(A)$?

In a [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/338941/525562), it was claimed that:

***Claim***
*Let $A$  be a nonempty compact subset of $\mathbb R^n$ with $\mu(A)>0$. Then for all $\delta>0$* 
$$\mu(A_\delta)\le \left(1+\delta\,\frac{\lambda(\partial A)}{n\,\mu(A)}\right)^n\mu(A)\tag1,$$ $A_\delta$ is the $\delta$-fattening of the set $A$, and $\lambda(\partial A)$ is the [Minkowski content](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%E2%80%93Steiner_formula)
$$\lambda(\partial A)=\liminf_{\delta\to 0}\delta^{-1}(\mu(A_\delta)-\mu(A))\tag2.$$
However, the proof utilized the fact that $f(\delta) = \left(\mu(A_\delta)/\mu(A)\right)^{1/n}$ is concave, which per [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1641264/concavity-of-the-nth-root-of-the-volume-of-r-neighborhoods-of-a-set) is not true. Can the claim above or a similar inequality be established?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/291561/relative-volume-increase-of-delta-fattening-of-a-compact-set?rq=1